# Regarding modified and modifying

Tags: grammaticality

> Component services could behave differently after **modifying** by service providers.

Is *modifying* correct? Can we use *modified* here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you should say one of the following.

> Component services could behave differently after **being modified** by service providers.

> Component services could behave differently after **modification** by service providers.

The first is an action; the second is an event. But I think the meaning of both is similar.

Answer (score 0):

If we wanted to use *modified*, the correct way to say it is the following:

> Component services could behave differently after being modified by service providers.

And yes it seems perfectly correct to me how it is.

The statement is basically talking of the change of state that it has undergone in order to reach how it is now. To do this it uses the verb in the gerund form first. So for an example both "after running for ten miles he was sweaty" and "after having ran for ten miles he was sweaty" are correct, whereas "after ran for ten miles" is not correct.

Comment: I think not. A gerund is active, and with it *by* calls for a means, not an agent; the use here requires *modification*. And it's after having *run*, not *ran*.

Comment: ing = gerund no? Sorry you mean that it should say, after modifying by (such thing) and not by (such person).

Comment: Exactly. In your 'after running' examples, the implicit subject of *running* is *he* - this is an active use. In OP's *after modifying* the gerund is passive, as your excellent rewrite shows: *after **being** modified*. You employ the gerund of *be*, so that the two clauses have the same subject.